# el PreparedStatement no me inserta los datos

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   Loading application [Matriz_riesgos] at [/Matriz_riesgos]
Información:   Matriz_riesgos was successfully deployed in 834 milliseconds.
Información:   java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mydb
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at Modelo.Conexion.getConecta(Conexion.java:29)
    at Modelo.EmpleadoDAO.CargoDAO.readAll(CargoDAO.java:171)
    at org.apache.jsp.registrausuarioa_jsp._jspService(registrausuarioa_jsp.java:69)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Modelo.EmpleadoDAO.CargoDAO.readAll(CargoDAO.java:171)
    at org.apache.jsp.registrausuarioa_jsp._jspService(registrausuarioa_jsp.java:69)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

> Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for
>   servlet jsp threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   Modelo.EmpleadoDAO.CargoDAO.readAll(CargoDAO.java:171)    at
>   org.apache.jsp.registrausuarioa_jsp._jspService(registrausuarioa_jsp.java:71)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.*;

/**
 *
 * @author MIGUEL ANGEL
 */
public class Conexion 
{


       public static Conexion Instance; 
       private  Connection connection;



       private Conexion() //Singleton

   {
           try
         {
            //obtenemos el driver de para mysql
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            //obtenemos la conexión
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mydb","root","");
            connection.setAutoCommit(true);

           if (connection!=null){
            System.out.println("Conexión a base de datos "+" OK\n");
         }


        }catch(SQLException e)
        {
         System.out.println(e);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e)

        {
         System.out.println(e);
          }catch(Exception e)
        {
         System.out.println(e);
        }

    }


   public static Conexion estado()//Singleton
   {
      if(Instance==null)
      {

        Instance= new Conexion();
      }

        return Instance;
   }        



   public Connection getConecta()
    {
      return connection;
    }

   public void desconectar()
    {
      connection= null;
    }


}
```

> Grave:   java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   Modelo.EmpleadoDAO.EmpleadoDAO.create(EmpleadoDAO.java:44)    at
>   Controlador.Insertaempleado.processRequest(Insertaempleado.java:66)
>     at Controlador.Insertaempleado.doGet(Insertaempleado.java:82)   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[image: descripción de la imagen aquí]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWdBT.png)

Estoy tratando de insertar a una tabla de empleado los datos desde un jsp, tengo una lista desplegble de cargos la cual lleno mediante un `ArrayList` recorro la lista con un `for-each` y obtengo el codigo del cargo para insertar a la tabla empleado , le hago debug y efectivamente todos los datos son transportados, pero al momento de insertar en la clase `empleadoDAO` salta el bloque de instrucción, pero si le quito la lista desplegable me inserta normal. No sé qué pueda estar pasando.

Voy a compartir el código de mi jsp y el código del servlet registra. Tengo un método abstracto que invoco para leer los datos de la base de datos al que invoco en el jsp.

JSP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<%
      //creacion objeto DAO se usa para invocar los metodos  que realizan las diferentes acciones en la base de datos
        CargoDAO c =new CargoDAO();
      //creacion de una arraylist de tipo CargoVO trae y almacena la lista de cargos el objeto "lista" mediante el metodo readAll que devuelve la lista cargos
       List <CargoVO>lista=c.readAll();
        // Recibe el objeto "myLista" mediante la sesion el cual viene del servlet controlador "Registra" 
       // luego es almacenado en una lista para posteriormente ser recorrido y asi extraer los valores
        //  ArrayList<CargoVO> listaCargo = (ArrayList<CargoVO>)request.getSession().getAttribute("myLista");


        %>
       <h1>Registro</h1>

        <form action="insertaempleado.do" method="get">

            Numero Identificacion<input type="text"  name="txtnit"  /> <br/> 
            Primer Nombre <input type="text"  name="txtnombrea"  /> <br/>
            Segundo Nombre <input type="text"  name="txtnombreb"  /> <br/>
            Primer Apellido <input type="text"  name="txtapellidoa"  /> <br/> 
            Segundo Apellido <input type="text"  name="txtapellidob"  /> <br/> 
            Fecha Nacimiento <input type="text"  name="txtnacimiento"  /> <br/>
            <%-- --   Id Cargo<input type="text"  name="txtcargo"  /> <br/> --%>




           Cargo
              <select name="cargo" >
                 <option value="0"> Seleccionar...</option>
             <%--creacion foreach para recorrer el objeto listaCargo --%>  
                <% for(CargoVO d :lista)
                   { %>
                <option value="<%= d.getCodigo() %>"> <%= d.getNombre() %> </option> 

                  <% }%>


           <input type="submit" value="Registrar">
         </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Código de clase `EmpleadoDAO`

```
public class EmpleadoDAO implements Obligatorio<EmpleadoVO>
{

    // Querys para trabajar sobre  la base de datos 
     private static final String SQL_Insert="INSERT INTO Empleado (Nit,Codigo_cargo,Primer_nombre,Segundo_Nombre,Apellido_paterno,Apellido_materno,Fecha_nacimiento) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";
     private static final String SQL_Delete="DELETE FROM Cargo WHERE Codigo= ?";
     private static final String SQL_Update="UPDATE Cargo SET  Nombre = ?  WHERE Codigo = ?";
     private static final String SQL_Read="SELECT * FROM Cargo WHERE Codigo = ?";
     private static final String SQL_Readall="SELECT * FROM Cargo";

      private static final Conexion con=Conexion.estado();

    @Override
    public boolean create(EmpleadoVO c) 
    {
             PreparedStatement ps;


         try {


             ps=con.getConecta().prepareStatement(SQL_Insert);

             ps.setInt(1,c.getNit());
             ps.setInt(2,c.getCargo());
             ps.setString(3, c.getPrimer_nombre());
             ps.setString(4,c.getSegundo_nombre());
             ps.setString(5, c.getApellido_paterno());
             ps.setString(6, c.getApellido_materno());
             ps.setString(7, c.getFecha_nacimiento());



          if(ps.executeUpdate()>0);
             {
                 return true;

             }

         } catch (SQLException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(CargoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }finally
         {
             con.desconectar();
         }

         return false;

    }



    @Override
    public boolean delete(Object key)
    { 
             PreparedStatement ps;

         try {

             ps=con.getConecta().prepareStatement(SQL_Delete);
             ps.setInt(1, key.hashCode());

             if(ps.executeUpdate()>0);
             {
                 return true;

             }
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(CargoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }finally
         {
             con.desconectar();
         }

         return false;

    }



    @Override
    public boolean update(EmpleadoVO c) 
    {
             PreparedStatement ps;

         try {

             ps=con.getConecta().prepareStatement(SQL_Update);

           //  ps.setString(1,c.getNombre());
          //   ps.setInt(2,c.getCodigo());

             if(ps.executeUpdate()>0);
             {
                 return true;

             } 

         } catch (SQLException ex) 
         {
             Logger.getLogger(CargoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }finally

         {
             con.desconectar();
         }
        return false;
    }



    @Override
    public EmpleadoVO read(Object key) 
    {

            EmpleadoVO empleado= null;
             PreparedStatement ps;
             ResultSet res;


     try {

             ps=con.getConecta().prepareStatement(SQL_Read);
             ps.setInt(1, key.hashCode());
             res=ps.executeQuery();

             while(res.next())
             {
                 empleado=new EmpleadoVO(res.getInt(1),res.getInt(2),res.getString(3),res.getString(4),res.getString(5),res.getString(6),res.getString(7));
             }

             return empleado;
         } catch (SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(CargoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }finally

         {
             con.desconectar();
         }

         return empleado;
    }

    @Override
    public List<EmpleadoVO> readAll()
    {
             PreparedStatement ps;
             ResultSet res;
             ArrayList<EmpleadoVO> empleado=new ArrayList<>();


         try {

             ps=con.getConecta().prepareStatement(SQL_Readall);
             res=ps.executeQuery();

             while(res.next())
             {

       empleado.add(new EmpleadoVO(res.getInt(1),res.getInt(2),res.getString(3),res.getString(4),res.getString(5),res.getString(6),res.getString(7)));
             }
         } catch (SQLException ex) 
         {
             Logger.getLogger(CargoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }finally

         {
             con.desconectar();
         }

         return empleado;
    }

}
```

Clase `Insertaempleado`:

```
public class Insertaempleado extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter())
        {
            int cod=0; 
            int cargo=0;

          String Nit=request.getParameter("txtnit");
          String Nombrea=request.getParameter("txtnombrea");
          String Nombreb=request.getParameter("txtnombreb");
          String Apellidoa=request.getParameter("txtapellidoa");
          String Apellidob=request.getParameter("txtapellidob");
          String Fechan=request.getParameter("txtnacimiento");
          String Cargo=request.getParameter("cargo");
          Fechan.trim();



            try
        {

            cod=Integer.parseInt(Nit);
            cargo=Integer.parseInt(Cargo);

        }catch(NumberFormatException exeption){}


         EmpleadoDAO c= new EmpleadoDAO(); 
         c.create(new EmpleadoVO(cod,cargo,Nombrea,Nombreb,Apellidoa,Apellidob,Fechan));
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como se muestra en el código de la clase `Conexion`, hay graves problemas. Aquí la descripción de los síntomas bajo el stacktrace y código provisto:

1. `Conexion` es una clase singleton que sirve para manejar una instancia de conexión a la base de datos como atributo interno: `private Connection connection`.
2. El método `Conexion#desconectar` cambia el valor de este atributo `connection` a `null`:

   ```
   public void desconectar() { connection= null; }
   ```
3. Cuando se ejecuta un método de la clase dao, al final se llama al método `Conexion#desconectar` (tomado de `EmpleadoDAO#create`):

   ```
   finally
    {
        con.desconectar();
    }
   ```
4. Al volver a llamar a un método de una clase dao para abrir la conexión, se utiliza `Conexion#getConecta()` el cual va a devolver el valor actual del atributo `connection`, el cual es `null` debido a lo explicado en el punto 3, por lo que salta el error `NullPointerException`. Ejemplo en `EmpleadoDAO#create`:

   ```
   public boolean create(EmpleadoVO c) 
   {
        PreparedStatement ps;
        try {
           //con.getConecta() trae null
           //por ende aquí salta un NullPointerException
           ps=con.getConecta().prepareStatement(SQL_Insert);
       //resto del código...
   ```

Esto explica los problemas que tienes.

¿Cómo resolverlos?

Primero que nada, **evita usar un singleton para manejar tus conexiones a base de datos**. En su lugar, lo que debes hacer es instanciar una conexión de base de datos por cada método. Esto resolverá tus problemas. De momento, la forma más sencilla es cambiar el contenido de `Conexion#getConecta` a que abra una conexión y la devuelva:

```
public Connection getConecta() {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        //desde Java 7 y drivers JDBC 4 esto ya no es necesario
        //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        //obtenemos la conexión
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mydb","root","");
        connection.setAutoCommit(true);

        if (connection!=null) {
            System.out.println("Conexión a base de datos "+" OK\n");
        }
    //si todas las excepciones las manejarás de la misma manera
    //entonces solo captura la excepción cuyo tipo sea super clase
    //de las demás
    //esto es, captura Exception solamente
    //} catch(SQLException e) {
    //    System.out.println(e);
    //} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    //    System.out.println(e);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return conn;
}
```

Asimismo, para cerrar una conexión, es mejor que el método `Conexion#desconectar` cambie a como sigue:

```
public void desconectar(Connection conn) {
    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

Esta es una solución momentánea. Como buena práctica, siempre debes abrir una conexión en el menor alcance posible (esto es, actualmente, en tus métodos de la clase dao).

Ahora, abrir una conexión física de base de datos es una operación costosa. En lugar de hacer esto, lo que deberías hacer es utilizar un pool de conexiones que administre las conexiones por ti y no te preocupas de abrir las conexiones manualmente puesto que el pool se encargará de mantener las conexiones en memoria por ti (evitando así el singleton y las malas prácticas como la que viste aquí).

Comment: gracias ya cambie la clase conexion pero ahora me da nullpointer en la clase que recorre la lista de la tabla que llena la lista desplegable y no me deja desplegar el jsp registro

Comment: y de nuevo siempre yo pruebo mis métodos desde el método main siempre construyo una clase test y funciona ahi ,la verdad ya no se porque me arroja error ese **javanullpointer**

Comment: Tendría que ver el nuevo StackTrace.

Comment: vale lo estoy actualizando pero de nuevo esta en la linea del preparestatement

Comment: al parecer es problema con el driver

Comment: ¿Utilizas el último driver de MySQL y Java 7 u 8?

Comment: puse  **Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");** de nuevo y me deja despleagar el jsp pero ahora me arroja un excepcion sql ya no es javanullpointer

Comment: Oh, al parecer no utilizas la última versión de Java o del driver para MySQL (lo cual es extraño porque esos cambios están presentes desde el 2014). Ya el otro problema es de lado de tu query. Revisa que funcione correctamente.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda ya lo solucione  y gracias a tu conexión me funciona mejor ya me inserta no me envia nulos ya funciona perfecto !! despues de 4 dias de buscar y buscar la solucion por fin!!! Mil gracias!

Comment: Puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada. Esa es la mejor forma de dar gracias en este sitio :)